# Local script is saying GD Library Isn't Installed

Tags: php, mamp

I'm running MAMP on my macbook, and I installed a script - it requires the GD Library.

I made a php info file and it says that gd is enabled/bundled.

The script requires it, and during install, it's saying the GD library isn't installed.

Any clue as to why it would be saying this??

Comment: Can you do a `php -m` from the command line and see if 'gd' is listed as an installed module?

Comment: How are you running the two scripts? php cli and sapi modes have two different .ini files, and gd could be loaded in only one of the two.

Comment: php -m does list gd.  The script is just installed in htdocs and the installer is a php file at localhost/admin/install.php

Comment: Are they both running the same PHP install?